# How to calculate percentage of each class variable after grouping it by another variable?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, counter

I have a data that initially looks like this:

| column1 | Time |
| --- | --- |
| yes | 271-273 |
| no | 271-273 |
| neutral | 271-273 |
| no | 274-276 |
| ... | ... |

I want the percentage of yes, percentage of no, and percentage of neutral across each Time range. I was able to get the count of each one of these categories (yes,no,neutral) across every time range using the following code:

```
df['COUNTER'] =1    
group_data = df.groupby(['Time','column1'])['COUNTER'].sum()
```

I am not sure how to calculate the percentage of counts from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with parameter `normalize=True`:

```
print (df)
   column1     Time
0      yes  271-273
1       no  271-273
2  neutral  271-273
3       no  271-273 <- changed data for better sample

group_data = (df.groupby(['Time'])['column1']
                .value_counts(normalize=True)
                .reset_index(name='%') )

print (group_data)
      Time  column1     %
0  271-273       no  0.50
1  271-273  neutral  0.25
2  271-273      yes  0.25
```

Another idea with divide by sum of counts with [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) and [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
s = df.groupby(['Time','column1']).size()
group_data = s.div(s.groupby(level=0).sum()).reset_index(name='%') 
print (group_data)

      Time  column1     %
0  271-273  neutral  0.25
1  271-273       no  0.50
2  271-273      yes  0.25
```